# How would you implement FHIR in PHP?

Tags: php, hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I am trying to build a webapp in PHP that implements HL7's standards. Then I came across FHIR. I do not have alot of experience with API's, though I do have some with some PHP frameworks.

When FHIR's documentation says it is a framework standard, does this mean it is not a framework in itself? I also read in the documentation that it provides a RESTful API. Though as a newbie in this kind of thing, I find myself a bit lost on where to start. But I still want to use FHIR, and implement it using PHP.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help and give me some insight on this.

Comment: Did you got any response to that topic?

Comment: Yes. Although I'm not working on the project anymore, I got some insight after some emails.

FHIR is not a framework. It is a framework _standard_. Like Lloyd McKenzie said, there are APIs for different languages but none for PHP yet (as far as I knew) What this means, if you plan to use PHP you will have to implement FHIR style routes yourself, as well as FHIR objects. I came across this library to generate FHIR objects in PHP: https://packagist.org/packages/dcarbone/php-fhir

You can implement their standards in most MVC frameworks. It is very large standard, I didn't expect to use all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FHIR provides a number of APIs for different languages (Java, C#, Javascript, etc.) but we don't yet have a reference implementation for PHP.  I'd suggest asking the question on http://chat.fhir.org on the implementer's stream and ask who else is using PHP.  It may be you'll need to create your own implementation.

Comment: Here's the thread: https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/implementers/subject/FHIR.20on.20PHP

Answer (score 0):

FHIR is just describing the standard, like a manual. the implementation, may be with a framework, relies on yourself.